# Why True/False is capitalized in Python?

Tags: python, camelcasing

All members are camel case, right? Why True/False but not true/false, which is more relaxed?

Comment: All members are camel case, right? No, it depends. Use **snake_case** to declare variables, functions, modules and packages (ex: first_name, calculate_sum). For Constants, use all uppercase and separate words by underscore if needed (ex: HEADING_COLOR). For classes, use **PascalCase** (ex: StudentRecords)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

From [Pep 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/):

> Should the constants be called 'True'
>   and 'False' (similar to
>          None) or 'true' and 'false' (as in C++, Java and C99)?
>
> => True and False.
>
> Most reviewers agree that consistency within Python is more
>   important than consistency with other languages.

This, as Andrew points out, is probably because [all (most)? built-in constants are capitalized](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html).

Comment: Thanks James, but isn't the default casing is camel casing in python?

Comment: It is for classes. There are different rules for other things.

Scroll to "Naming Conventions": http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: In that case, how come other constants aren't lower case also?

Comment: the real question is: Why is 'None' capitalized in the first place? I get errors again and again because I write a constant in lowercase...

Answer (score 18):

All of python's [built-in constants](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html) are capitalized or [upper] CamelCase:

Comment: @Andrew: Don't you mean PascalCased rather than camelCased ?

Comment: @Kev, yes, but technically, I think "upper CamelCase" is the same as PascalCase.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [possible explaination](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-May/440165.html):

> > I see that naming conventions are such that classes usually get named
> >     CamelCase. So why are the built-in types named all lowercase (like
> >     list, dict, set, bool, etc.)?
>
> Because most of them originally were
>   types and factory functions, not
>   classes - and a naming convention is
>   not a strong reason to make backwards 
>   incompatible changes. A different
>   example: the new builtin type `set` is
>   based on (altough not   exactly equal
>   to) the Set class from the sets module

Answer (score -4):

In python only the 3 keywords True ,False and None are started with capital letters. I think This is to differentiate these 3 keywords from others. These 3 keywords can be used as literals or values where as other keywords not.
For example

a=True      is correct
but
a=for       is wrong

Comment: This is a wrong comment, as you have Ellipsis, NotImplemented