# What is the history behind capitalization of None, True and False in Python?

Tags: python, pep8

Python has some of the value-like objects capitalized: `True`, `False`, `None`.

```
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

As the current PEP-8 style guide recommends writing instances and variable names in lowercase, what is the history behind writing these value-like objects capitalized?

As it is answered / commented that built-ins are capitalized, but what is the rationale and inspiration behind this? In most languages built-ins are all uppercase, so one would expect Python to follow this paradigm?

Comment: Please see the clarification in the question

Comment: Ah, found this answer pointing to a dead link http://stackoverflow.com/a/521509/315168

Comment: In which most languages? I can actually think of only one mainstream language where built-in or standard non-types are CamelCase, C#, and it's only because it has almost everything CamelCase.

Comment: None, True, and False may be capitalized since you can assign them to variables?

Answer (score 4):

The goal of Python is consistency within itself, not consistency to other languages. `True` and `False` are capitalized because most, if not all, built in constants are capitalized. While I am not aware of exactly why it is done, it is probably because it is easier to differentiate them from variables when the first letter is capitalized, as if it is lowercase, it is easy to confuse it with a variable.

Comment: Please see the clarification in the question